# Syntax Error in Stored Procedure with CASE expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax

```
CASE
   WHEN authorizedID = dbo.CUSTOMER_TABLE.authorizedID 
     THEN authorizedID 
     ELSE NULL 
END AS authorizedID,
```

I want to match `authorizedID` with different table's column `dbo.CUSTOMER_TABLE.authorizedID`.

If `authorizedID` is equals to `dbo.CUSTOMER_TABLE.authorizedID` then I want to get `authorizedID else null`.

However I get syntax error for `dbo.CUSTOMER_TABLE.authorizedID`:

> The multi part identifier dbo.CUSTOMER_TABLE.authorizedID could not be
>   bound

Where I miss by writing stored procedure?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What's wrong with coalesce? And also: show the full sql statement!

Comment: first of all I'd try to use different name for your variable/column/alias to be sure that is not the problem

Comment: This is not a syntax error, it is stating that there is no object in query (within scope) called `dbo.CUSTOMER_TABLE`. Is this table/view in your from clause? Have you given it an alias?

Comment: @DavidBrabant - The OP is asking for an anti-`COALESCE` that returns NULL if there is a mismatch between values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case the code must be as following:

```
CASE
   WHEN authorizedID in (select distinct authorizedID from dbo.CUSTOMER_TABLE)
     THEN authorizedID 
     ELSE NULL 
END AS authorizedID
```

Otherwise you can make left join with this table (`dbo.CUSTOMER_TABLE`) and, after this, define the *`CASE`* condition. In this case performance will be much better.